# Удалить ненужный div при парсинге

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Парсим таблицу и в таблице есть не нужный нам `div`.

Как его удалить средствами *PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser* или другими?

Код:

```
$table = $html_product->find('.product-features__table tbody',0);
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowa) {

        $th = $rowa->find('th');
        $td = $rowa->find('td');
        $th = implode($th);
        $td = implode($td);


        $theData[] = "Характеристики|".$th."|".$td;
    }
    $links_product['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = $theData;
```

Почти в каждом `th` есть div его класс `product-hint`. Этот `div` мне и нужно удалить со всем его содержимым.

Код не совсем шикарный, т.к. для разового использования.

Comment: попробуйте найти его и сказать, что  `->outterHTML ='';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = str_get_html($txt);
foreach($html->find(".product-hint") as $ph) $ph->outertext = '';

echo $html;
```

удаляет  все элементы с классом `product-hint`